# How do I use HTML or CSS to put checkboxes before the text question?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I am trying to create a webform. The checkboxes are coming after the label and therefore all the checkboxes are not lined up. How can I get the checkboxes to come before the text?

```html
<label for="needs">Please select if you have: </label>
<p>
  <p>
    <label for="monitor" class="checkboxes">Monitor(s)
            <input  id="monitor" name="monitor" type="checkbox" value="1" /><br>

            </label>
    <label for="Keyboard" class="checkboxes">Keyboard 
            <input  id="Keyboard" name="Keyboard" type="checkbox" value="1" /><br>
            </label>
    <label for="Mouse" class="checkboxes">Mouse
            <input  id="Mouse" name="Mouse" type="checkbox" value="1" /><br>
            </label>
    <label for="Dock" class="checkboxes">Docking Station
            <input  id="Dock" name="Dock" type="checkbox" value="1" /><br>
            </label>
    <label for="webcam" class="checkboxes">Webcam
            <input  id="webcam" name="webcam" type="checkbox" value="1" /><br>
            </label>
    <label for="Printer" class="checkboxes">Printer 
            <input  id="Printer" name="Printer" type="checkbox" value="1" /><br>

            </label>
```

Comment: The HTML is ... while not "invalid" per se ... certainly odd. There's a `label` pointing to nothing (there is no element with the id "needs"). There are two opening `p` elements, one nested in the other, which is odd. Also, you don't need `for` on a `label` that wraps its element. Nothing inherently wrong with it, just redundant. Also, using `<br>` is somewhat passe, as you can use CSS to create the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the checkbox inputs before the labels.

```html
<label for="needs">Please select if you have: </label>
<p></p>
<label class="checkboxes"><input id="monitor" name="monitor" type="checkbox" value="1" /> Monitor(s)</label><br>
<label class="checkboxes"><input id="Keyboard" name="Keyboard" type="checkbox" value="1" /> Keyboard</label><br>
<label class="checkboxes"><input id="Mouse" name="Mouse" type="checkbox" value="1" /> Mouse</label><br>
<label class="checkboxes"><input id="Dock" name="Dock" type="checkbox" value="1" /> Docking Station</label><br>
<label class="checkboxes"><input id="webcam" name="webcam" type="checkbox" value="1" /> Webcam</label><br>
<label class="checkboxes"><input id="Printer" name="Printer" type="checkbox" value="1" /> Printer</label><br>
```

Comment: I tried doing that, that was my first thought, but then the text goes all the way right justified. I am guessing there is something wonky going on with the css. Thank you!

Comment: Almost certainly. Use the `Run code snippet` button above to see the checkboxes without any style

Answer (score 0):

place the `label` after the `input`,

In this case, there is no need for the `input` to be inside the `label`, as shown [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_checkbox.asp)

if necessary, use a `div` to wrap the `label` and the `input` as in the example here.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<label for="needs">Please select if you have: </label>
<p><p>

<div>
  <input  id="monitor" name="monitor" type="checkbox" value="1" />
  <label for="monitor" class="checkboxes">Monitor(s)</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input  id="Keyboard" name="Keyboard" type="checkbox" value="1" />
  <label for="Keyboard" class="checkboxes">Keyboard</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input  id="Mouse" name="Mouse" type="checkbox" value="1" />
  <label for="Mouse" class="checkboxes">Mouse</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input  id="Dock" name="Dock" type="checkbox" value="1" />
  <label for="Dock" class="checkboxes">Docking Station</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input  id="webcam" name="webcam" type="checkbox" value="1" />
  <label for="webcam" class="checkboxes">Webcam</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input  id="Printer" name="Printer" type="checkbox" value="1" />
  <label for="Printer" class="checkboxes">Printer</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Now my label is underneath the checkbox. Honestly, the text wants to be anywhere BUT where I want it to be.

Comment: _"The label element should be separate from the input"_ Not true

Comment: Nope =( I am going to take another look at what is going on with my styling. Clearly something is being weird. Thank you for the help!

Comment: HTML does not (nor any accessibility standard) dictate that the `label` must be separate from the `input` and in fact includes wrapping the `input` as a standard method for associating a `label` with an `input`. Please cite references for such statements.

Comment: I didn't mean that the `label` must be separate from the `input`, only that in this case the `input` not need to be inserted into the `label`, I am editing the answer according to your comment